# the question of enable "mobile switch"

Tags: theming

I install the module of "mobile switch" and enable it.
But I just only enable this module and set a mobile theme, the error message is showed:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ismobiledevice in mobile_switch_boot() (line 40 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\mobile_switch\mobile_switch.module).
```

I don't know how to solve it.
Have anyone know what'w happen?
Thanks....

Comment: I have solved it.
I add initialization in mobile_switch_browscap_get_browser()


$browser['ismobiledevice'] = '0'


but I still can't switch theme on mobile device.
I don't know where is wrong...

Comment: Clearly this is a module bug, and should be filed as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try an alternative [Theme key](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module rather then using [mobile switch](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_switch) module to check for the mobile device.
It provides flexibility for changing the theme not only based on the type of device but also can theme different parts of site based on different conditions.
You can check for a detailed [video tutorial](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode52) by Mustardseed to check this features.