# How to redirect a user to mobile site?

Tags: theming

I have created a Drupal 7 site with all required functions. As per the requirement I have to create a mobile theme for this site, which I did effectively. Now problem is I need to redirect the user to the mobile site if the request is made from a mobile. If the request is made from computer he should be redirected to the main site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could see my [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32464/the-question-of-enable-mobile-switch/32494#32494) for the same issue :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already existing modules to do it like [mobile_tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools). Where u can set what theme to use for mobiles. and redirection on mobile detection also.

Comment: @slassenger - Welcome :)

Comment: can u say few modules that can work with D7 as well.

Comment: @slassenger - check this link for 7 version of mobile tools http://drupal.org/node/416196/release

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Tools is a good option, or you may use [theme_key](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) just as well.

Regards.

Comment: thanks for ur reply:):) Hacker's answer solved the problem. But still need to work with D7.